# node.js scheduler is not working in production environment.( google cloud Linux Debian server)

Tags: linux, node.js

i want to send reminder mails from node js server. for that i used node.js scheduler

it is sending mail in localhost(development environment) , but when i am deploying it to google cloud (Linux Debian server)  it is not sending mail on specific (saved time).

so anyone can tell me how can i rectify it.?

Comment: Is there a specific error?  Is in not sending emails at all, or is it just a specific time of day? Have you made sure the appropriate dependencies have been installed?  You should also show what you've tried, your work.  Anything that could help us narrow down the culprit.

Comment: @Squeegy , their is no any specific Error, and mail is not going from production server at all ,Actually i am not able to see error also , i am new to linux ,  we have to send thousands of reminder mail daily do i need to setup new mail server? or simply gmail service will work ?